# Simulate async await in node-red/vanilla js function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, aws-sdk, node-red

I am using node-red flow and inside I have a node function that does something like this:

```
s3.getObject(params, function(err,data) {

    if (!err && data && data.Body) {
        msg.s3aka = data.Body.toString()
    }
});

while (true) {
    if (msg.s3aka)
        break;
    let start = new Date().getTime();
    while (true) { // delay 100ms
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > 100){
            break;
        }
    }
}

return msg;
```

So I wait for the result (msg.s3aka) to be set to return the msg. This looks ugly and I can't use async/await inside node function (not support ES 7). If I use Promise the last line (return msg) will be executed before msg.s3aka is set. So is there a better way to do this using vanilla javascript?

Edit: This is not solved by [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) since it is specific to node-red. I tried various ways including using date, async await, promise.
I solved this by using node.send(msg) in the callback.

Comment: Nothing about `s3.getObject` and its asynchronous callback is specific to node-red?

Comment: And the Node-RED function editor may flag errors but still run the code if Node-RED is running on a new enough version of NodeJS, it's just that code editor doesn't understand the new syntax